# Last digit of year with DateTimeFormatter

Tags: java, date, java-8, java-time

For year `2014` I want to display `4` and for `2029 -> 9`

I know how to format with 4 digits => `yyyy`, and two digits => `yy`

But I can't understand, how to do it with one last digit

```
DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yMMdd"); //returns 20151020. I want just 51020
```

Comment: What would be the difference between 2015 and 2025 then?

Comment: @Tunaki I see your point, but this is not important in my case

Comment: Format with two year digits and remove the first character.

Comment: @Tunaki The difference is 10 years! if there is a need to keep 10 years data, then they will not choice this date format in the first place

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unlikely that `DateTimeFormatter` supports such an unusual requirement. If you have the year as an integral type, then use

`year % 10`

to extract the rightmost digit.

Comment: Actually, it is possible, see my answer.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by building your own `DateTimeFormatter` (and not relying on calculating substrings that can fail if your pattern evolves) like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                        .appendValueReduced(ChronoField.YEAR, 1, 1, 0)
                                        .appendPattern("MMdd")
                                        .toFormatter();
System.out.println(LocalDate.now().format(formatter)); // prints 51020
System.out.println(LocalDate.of(2029, 1, 1).format(formatter)); // prints 90101
```

However, this formatter can only be used to format a `LocalDate` and can't be used to parse a `LocalDate`.

[`appendValueReduced`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatterBuilder.html#appendValueReduced-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-int-int-int-) is used to format a reduced value of a temporal field. In this case, we are appending a value of fixed width 1 and saying that the base value is 0 (this way, valid values will be between 0 and 9).

Comment: This will parse fine. The last argument (base value) is the base year, so setting it to 2010 (instead of 0) will parse dates from 2000 to 2009. So long as the base year ends in zero, formatting the date will be fine.

Comment: can you please explain what is base value for a little more? can't get it :(

Comment: @VextoR I'm quoting the Javadoc that says it better than I: "For example, a base value of 1980 and a width of 2 will have valid values from 1980 to 2079. During parsing, the text "12" will result in the value 2012 as that is the value within the range where the last two characters are "12". "

Answer (score 2):

```
String sb = new SimpleDateFormat("yyMMdd").format(new Date());
        System.out.println(sb); // prints 151020
        sb = sb.substring(1, sb.length()); //remove 1st char
        System.out.println(sb); //prints 51020
```

Answer (score 1):

That won't be possible with DateTimeFormatter. Check this link:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx

"y" formatter should throw year from 0 to 99

You simply should extract the last digit by yourself and create the string.